# Amazon RDS and Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, zend-framework2

I am having problem connecting to my Amazon RDS database from [a Zend Framework 2 tutorial application.](http://akrabat.com/wp-content/uploads/Getting-Started-with-Zend-Framework-2.pdf)

I keep getting the following error:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'db_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\wamp\www\zf2-tutorial\vendor\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Connection.php on line 214
```

I have no problem connecting to the database using MySQL Workbench or Toad so I don't think the DB Security Group is the issue. Also, the PHP application connects to the local database just fine too.

I am wondering why the error message says `db_user'@'localhost`. Shouldn't it say `db_user'@'RDS host url`?

My connection string is:

```
'driver' => array(
'driver' => 'Pdo',
'dsn' => 'mysql:hostname=xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com;dbname=zf2-tutorial',
'username' => 'db_user',
'password' => 'xxxxxxx',
'driver_options' => array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
),
```

Comment: Username/Password are incorrect.

Comment: Your host need to be an ip or website of RDS.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the problem is in the dsn string, unlike other MySQL servers, Amazon RDS does not understand "hostname". If changed to "host" it works just fine!

'dsn' => 'mysql:**host**=xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com;dbname=zf2-tutorial',

Thanks for all the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Add the host variable to your config, as per Zend's documentation

```
'driver' => array(
    'driver' => 'Pdo',
    'dsn' => 'mysql:hostname=xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com;dbname=zf2-tutorial',
    'username' => 'db_user',
    'password' => 'xxxxxxx',
    'host'  => 'xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com', // Possible here
    'driver_options' => array(
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
    ),
),
'host'  => 'xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com', // Most likely here
```

Answer (score 1):

The MySQL PDO DSN expects **host**, not hostname:

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php

I've just made the same mistake following a ZF2 tutorial, baffled as to why the config was ignoring a hostname change, until I read the PHP PDO doc, changed it to **host** (as you  have) and magically everything worked as it should